# Translate the newline character in a series. optimization

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series of strings with escape chars in it, like this

```
s = pd.Series(['potato\n\r','corn\n\r','pinea\n apple','\r potato\n head'])
```

So i did this to remove them

```
s.apply(lambda s: s.translate({10:'',13 : ''}))
# Remove newline and carriage ret
```

The thing is I am not sure, if this is the most optimal way of doing it and since the data is quite a biggie I would like some inputs.
A thing to know is that the strings in my real life data do not contain the escape chars. Filtering it, and replacing only on valid strings maybe more efficient than the way I am currently doing it but I don't know how to map that. Would appreciate some help on this performance improvement?

Answer (score 1):

perhaps using regex, replace all occurrence of \n or \r with an empty string

```
s.replace(r'[\n|\r]', '', regex=True)
```

```
0          potato
1            corn
2     pinea apple
3     potato head
dtype: object
```

Comment: I am gonna test it out and come back with a response

Comment: It seens my way is a little faster no clue on the why, but appreaciate your input